Angle made by vector with another vector upon rotation in different plane than the two vectors themselves?
A vector $w$ makes an angle of $60$ degrees with two vectors $u$ and $v$ each in a plane other than that of plane $u-v$ itself. Keeping $u$ fixed if the vector $v$ is rotated by $x$ degrees in the $u-v$ plane such that vectors $u$ and $v$ become perpendicular to each other, then what is the new angle between vector $w$ and vector $v$?
I just cannot think of how to approach this problem or even the initial steps. I feel that we would need to apply the cosine property for vector $w$ for 3 perpendicular axes somewhere -
$(\cos x)^2 + (\cos y)^2 + (\cos z)^2 = 1$, where $x, y$ and $z$ are the perpendicular axes
but I can't think of how to get there.

Without loss of generality, assume all vectors have length $1$. Then let's add a coordinate system, where $\hat i$ is along $u$, $\hat j$ is perpendicular to $\hat i$ in the $u-v$ plane, and $\hat k$ is perpendicular to the plane. Since rotating $v$ by $x$ degrees you get to be perpendicular to $u$, it means that the original angle is $90^\circ -x$. We can now write the components of all vectors:
$$u=\hat i\\v=\cos(90^\circ-x)\hat i+\sin(90^\circ-x)\hat j\\w=\sin\theta\cos\phi\hat i+\sin\theta\sin\phi\hat j+\cos\theta\hat k$$
Here the vector $w$ components are written in terms of a polar representation. Then write the cosine of the angles between $w$ and $u$ and $w$ and $v$:
$$\cos(60^\circ)=1/2=u\cdot w=\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\cos(60^\circ)=1/2=v\cdot w=\sin\theta\cos\phi\cos(90^\circ-x)+\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin(90^\circ-x)$$
What you are looking for is the angle between $w$ and $\hat j$, let's call this $\alpha$. $$\cos\alpha=w\cdot\hat j=\sin\theta\sin\phi$$
I hope you can finish this.

Here's how you do this: First, note that since $u\times v$ is orthogonal to the $u,v$ plane, it is the rotation axis for $v$. With this, it should be easy to work out the transformation of $v$ by using the axis-angle parametrization. Once you have the transformation, plug that into the usual formula for angles between vectors, and you are done.
